# Bootstrap sidenav scroll

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am playing around with [this](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html) bootstrap template ( [github](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella), [emptypage](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella/blob/master/production/empty.html) code which I use ) and mostly just interested in the sidebar. However I cant seem to get scrollspy working on it in case the side menu gets too long. This is what I have:

```
<div class="col-md-3 left_col">
    <div class="left_col scroll-view">

        <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
            <a href="#" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> <span>Engine of Travel</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- menu prile quick info -->
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile_pic">
                <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_info">
                <span>Welcome,</span>

                <h2>User</h2><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /menu quick info -->

        <br/>

        <!-- sidebar menu -->
        <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

            <div class="menu_section">
                <h3>Side Side</h3>
                <ul class="nav side-menu">
                    <li><a><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Sidething <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav child_menu" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#child_menu" style="display: none">
                            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a>
                            </li>
                            ...
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $("#child_menu").scrollspy();
</script>
```

The menu generated displays elements that can fit in the screen and after that 'breaks' as you can see in the image. WHat would be the best way to get scroll to work.

[image: broken scroll]

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors when it breaks? Are you using any custom CSS code? Could you reproduce your issue in a js.fiddle?

Comment: I tried using codepen. However since there are a couple of custom css files, I cant reproduce the exact look and feel

Comment: @crazymatt - http://codepen.io/isharief318/pen/pyVmNX